# I want to convert MathML to LaTeX

Tags: msword, mathml

I'm trying to convert my equations I make in Microsoft Office Word 2013 to LaTeX because I would like to post my equations I make in word at [math.stackexchange.com](http://math.stackexchange.com).

I'm able to convert it to MathML. But if I post it here it doesn't really look like it should be. Is it possible to convert MathML to LaTeX?

```xml
<math xmlns:mml="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
    <mtable>
        <mtr>
            <mtd>
                <mrow>
                    <maligngroup/>
                    <mi>a</mi>
                    <mo>&lt;</mo>
                    <mi>x</mi>
                    <mo>&lt;</mo>
                    <mi>a</mi>
                    <mo>+</mo>
                    <msub>
                        <mrow>
                            <mi>δ</mi>
                        </mrow>
                        <mrow>
                            <mn>1</mn>
                        </mrow>
                    </msub>
                    <malignmark/>
                    <mo>⇒</mo>
                    <mfenced open="|" close="|" separators="|">
                        <mrow>
                            <msub>
                                <mrow>
                                    <mi>f</mi>
                                </mrow>
                                <mrow>
                                    <mn>1</mn>
                                </mrow>
                            </msub>
                            <mfenced separators="|">
                                <mrow>
                                    <mi>x</mi>
                                </mrow>
                            </mfenced>
                            <mo>-</mo>
                            <msub>
                                <mrow>
                                    <mi>L</mi>
                                </mrow>
                                <mrow>
                                    <mn>1</mn>
                                </mrow>
                            </msub>
                        </mrow>
                    </mfenced>
                    <mo>&lt;</mo>
                    <mfrac>
                        <mrow>
                            <msub>
                                <mrow>
                                    <mi>L</mi>
                                </mrow>
                                <mrow>
                                    <mn>1</mn>
                                </mrow>
                            </msub>
                            <mo>-</mo>
                            <msub>
                                <mrow>
                                    <mi>L</mi>
                                </mrow>
                                <mrow>
                                    <mn>2</mn>
                                </mrow>
                            </msub>
                        </mrow>
                        <mrow>
                            <mn>2</mn>
                        </mrow>
                    </mfrac>
                </mrow>
            </mtd>
        </mtr>
        <mtr>
            <mtd>
                <mrow>
                    <maligngroup/>
                    <malignmark/>
                    <mo>⇒</mo>
                    <msub>
                        <mrow>
                            <mi>L</mi>
                        </mrow>
                        <mrow>
                            <mn>1</mn>
                        </mrow>
                    </msub>
                    <mo>-</mo>
                    <mfrac>
                        <mrow>
                            <msub>
                                <mrow>
                                    <mi>L</mi>
                                </mrow>
                                <mrow>
                                    <mn>1</mn>
                                </mrow>
                            </msub>
                            <mo>-</mo>
                            <msub>
                                <mrow>
                                    <mi>L</mi>
                                </mrow>
                                <mrow>
                                    <mn>2</mn>
                                </mrow>
                            </msub>
                        </mrow>
                        <mrow>
                            <mn>2</mn>
                        </mrow>
                    </mfrac>
                    <mo>&lt;</mo>
                    <msub>
                        <mrow>
                            <mi>f</mi>
                        </mrow>
                        <mrow>
                            <mn>1</mn>
                        </mrow>
                    </msub>
                    <mfenced separators="|">
                        <mrow>
                            <mi>x</mi>
                        </mrow>
                    </mfenced>
                    <mo>&lt;</mo>
                    <msub>
                        <mrow>
                            <mi>L</mi>
                        </mrow>
                        <mrow>
                            <mn>1</mn>
                        </mrow>
                    </msub>
                    <mo>+</mo>
                    <mfrac>
                        <mrow>
                            <msub>
                                <mrow>
                                    <mi>L</mi>
                                </mrow>
                                <mrow>
                                    <mn>1</mn>
                                </mrow>
                            </msub>
                            <mo>-</mo>
                            <msub>
                                <mrow>
                                    <mi>L</mi>
                                </mrow>
                                <mrow>
                                    <mn>2</mn>
                                </mrow>
                            </msub>
                        </mrow>
                        <mrow>
                            <mn>2</mn>
                        </mrow>
                    </mfrac>
                </mrow>
            </mtd>
        </mtr>
        <mtr>
            <mtd>
                <mrow>
                    <maligngroup/>
                    <malignmark/>
                    <mo>⇒</mo>
                    <mfrac>
                        <mrow>
                            <msub>
                                <mrow>
                                    <mi>L</mi>
                                </mrow>
                                <mrow>
                                    <mn>1</mn>
                                </mrow>
                            </msub>
                            <mo>+</mo>
                            <msub>
                                <mrow>
                                    <mi>L</mi>
                                </mrow>
                                <mrow>
                                    <mn>2</mn>
                                </mrow>
                            </msub>
                        </mrow>
                        <mrow>
                            <mn>2</mn>
                        </mrow>
                    </mfrac>
                    <mo>&lt;</mo>
                    <msub>
                        <mrow>
                            <mi>f</mi>
                        </mrow>
                        <mrow>
                            <mn>1</mn>
                        </mrow>
                    </msub>
                    <mo>(</mo>
                    <mi>x</mi>
                    <mo>)</mo>
                </mrow>
            </mtd>
        </mtr>
    </mtable>
    <mi> </mi>
</math>
```

It should look like this:

https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=8FEA31C0ACCF70F0!135

[image]

Comment: A quick google would have led you to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9751191/219352)

Comment: I've seen that one, but Sciwriter crashes in windows 7. And pandoc doesn't seem to do MathML to Latex.

Comment: I was thinking that using mathjax there should be a way to do this. But I've no idea how.

Comment: If the system on Maths-SX were set up correctly (and I have no information as to whether it is or isn't) you wouldn't have to do this.  MathJaX can accept MathML as its input so you *ought* to be able to post raw MathML and have it just work.  But I expect that the HTML sanitiser on the SE network wouldn't allow that.  Shame.

Comment: @AndrewStacey just looked at a math.sx page they use  `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML">` so are only configured for tex-like input.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The XSLT at

https://github.com/davidcarlisle/web-xslt/tree/master/pmml2tex

converts MathML to TeX it's been fairly extensively used over the years including generating almost all the images in Chapter 4 of the MathML3 spec (as part of a pipeline Content MathML to Presentation MathML to TeX to images.)

It currently skips `maligngroup` and produces

[image]

From the supplied XML.

It would be trivial to add the extra `&` by hand to restore the alignment. Changing `matrix` to `aligned` and adding two `&` produces

[image]

Comment: Ok, thank you very much.
I hope this is what I'm looking for. 
But I've absolutely no idea how to use this.
Could you help me? How do I download these files ?

Comment: Wow ! freaking awesome ! How did you do that ?!

Comment: @KasperPeulen, well I have used LaTeX and MathML before:-)

Comment: You can download the files by going to http://code.google.com/p/web-xslt/source/browse/trunk/pmml2tex/ and looking at each and clicking on "raw file" over on the left.  you then need an xslt2 engine (eg saxon) and `java -jar saxon9.jar myfile.xml pmml2tex.xsl`  will produce the tex output.   saxon is free but off topic here.

Comment: Okay, I need to go now.
But tonight I'm going to try to get similar results as you got.
Thank you very much !

Answer (score 5):

My answer is probably not directly following your question but I think it is useful to mention the [Mathtype equation editor](http://www.dessci.com/en/products/mathtype/). This is a commercial product that plugs into Word and it allows export or conversion to LaTeX equations directly from the word document. This will remove one step from your work flow and may make sense if you need to make many conversions.

Comment: Using the mathtype converter, I'm able to get very good and quick results. The only problem is that the alignment breaks, but this is quickly restored. Awesome !