# How to Copy Latex from MS Equation Editor 3.0

Tags: equations, amsmath, msword

I've one word document having equations typed using MS Equation Editor 3.0 ; One Sample Screenshot is mentioned below: 
[image]

How can I get underlying AMS-Latex code for equation added using MS Equation Editor?

Comment: Does Word's equation editor support exporting their code to `LaTeX`?  I am not sure it would but I don't use Word.

Comment: I'm not sure about it, while searching over internet, found one url : http://ex-ample.blogspot.in/2012/06/how-to-import-or-export-latex-equation.html ; it seems there are some tools using which conversion is possible. Still checking to see if there are any simpler options.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs more to superuser.SX 

Comment: Several similar questions on TeX.SX: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27731/how-can-i-convert-from-microsoft-word-to-a-latex-document, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46015/converting-ms-word-doc-to-latex-by-command-line, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85639/i-want-to-convert-mathml-to-latex

Comment: @KevinC Those focus on using command-line tools to do conversion of either entire `.doc` files other formats, which go in the 'support for LaTeX' category (or at least close enough to be on topic). Your question seems to be about the Word GUI, which is distinct and not on-topic for us.

Comment: @JosephWright: I'm not the one who asked the question... I just referred the OP to some other posts that might be useful.

Comment: @KevinC Oh yes, sorry I'd missed that :-) Point stands though that my feeling is this one is off-topic as it's about the Word GUI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think that this is possible with MS Equation Editor 3.0. But it is possible with MathType (a commercial software product, [Link](http://www.dessci.com/en/products/mathtype/)).

I made a LaTeX introduction in German - here are the relevant slides:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks Manuel, I've used MathType in the past. Today received one MS document where symbols and formule are entered using MS Equation Editor, So checking if similar output is possible to get directly from equation editor 3.0

Comment: I see. Maybe you can use MathType to open the document and then convert the equations. There's a 30 days trial version available.

Comment: Thanks Manuel ; i've installed trial version and using same.